# Does 1 gb Ram enough for my 30,000 products in my site

Tags: magento

In my site have 30,000 products are there, is enough for my import and export processing.

Comment: I guess the answer depends on what you're using to do your import and export processing?

Comment: yes, in my site have 30,000 products

Comment: Yes.  Are you using Magento's import/export? Dataflow? Magmi?

Comment: minimum of products export working, but  bulk product export only not woking

Comment: how can i solve this   http://i.stack.imgur.com/v3eR8.png

Comment: Set a profile below.

Comment: Whole machine? No. Per php instance? Possibly 768M would be sufficient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?